# How to access an array from another class that is private in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, if-statement, private

I have 2 classes set up in a project where i am creating a primitive chess game. I am trying to access an array from another class but it's private. How would i go about referencing and accessing that array from a different class? Here are the sections of relavent code:

```
private static final char FREE         = '.';
private static final char WHITEROOK    = '♖';
private static final char BLACKROOK    = '♜';
private static final char WHITEBISHOP  = '♗';
private static final char BLACKBISHOP  = '♝';

private int boardsize;
private char[][] board;

public Board() {
    this.boardsize = DEFAULT_SIZE;

    board = new char[boardsize][boardsize];

    // Clear all playable fields
    for(int x=0; x<boardsize; x++)
        for(int y=0; y<boardsize; y++)
            board[x][y] = FREE;

    // Placing Initial Pieces on the board
    board[2][0] = WHITEBISHOP;
    board[5][0] = WHITEBISHOP;
    board[2][7] = BLACKBISHOP;
    board[5][7] = BLACKBISHOP;
    board[0][0] = WHITEROOK;
    board[7][0] = WHITEROOK;
    board[0][7] = BLACKROOK;
    board[7][7] = BLACKROOK;
}
```

It's the board array that I want to access, and use to compare to other arrays within if statements.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does another class need direct access to the array?  In general, try not to expose the inner workings of a class.  Instead, provide methods within the class that gives other classes the info they need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is probably not to allow any other class access the array directly and only let the Board class itself do that.

This could be done by creating public methods for moving a piece, printing the board etc

Here is a very simplified example

```
public void move(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY {
    char piece = board[fromX][fromY];
    board[toX][toY] = piece;
}
```

The usage in another class would then be

```
Board b = new Board();
b.move(4,1,4,3);
```

---

You say you want to compare the array to other arrays but that is also better if it's handled by the Board class

```
public int compareWith(char[][] otherArray) {
    int result = 0;
    //compare
    return result;
}
```

or even better, if you are comparing two boards then it would be

```
public int compareWith(Board otherBoard) {
    int result = 0;
    //compare
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hiya! Thanks for the answer. Does this mean that changing the layout of the board would not be possible from another class?

Comment: @LiamKr What do you mean with layout, not the size of the board or?

Comment: i meant change values of the arrays from a different class

Comment: @LiamKr, that is what my `move()` method does. So the other class will then call this method to change the layout.

Answer (score -1):

welcome to SO!

The traditional solutions to this would be either to make the field public:

```
public char[][] board;
```

or, probably safer and more common, create a getter method:

```
private char[][] board;
public char[][] getBoard() {
  return board;
}
```

Then, in the other class, you can create a `Board` and access its `board` using the getter:

```
Board myBoard = new Board();
char[][] boardArray = myBoard.getBoard();
//use the array:
System.out.println(boardArray[0][2]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't upvote you because of my low reputation, but i definitely would if i could! How would i then reference that array in my other class?

Comment: I've added a sample of how to access the array from another class. If I've solved your problem please click the check to mark as accepted.

Comment: I suppose that it would be difficult to change the layout of the board from within another class called game.java

Answer (score -1):

try to create a public method returning an array, or changing its insides

example

```
public void EditArray(int index1, int index2, char value){ board[index1][index2] = value; }
```

getting the values of the array directly will not work, you will have to write methods anyway (sorry my English)

Comment: and getting the values like this: public char[][] GetBoard() { return board; }